# How to print or echo the array index of in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printing, echo

I'm trying to complete my assignment and this is the last thing to do now.

I know if I want to print the whole array I can just use `foreach` and many different method to print the entire array

```
foreach($v as $k=>$variable_name) { echo "<p> This is index of $k. value is $variable_name <br/></p>";}
```

But what if I want to only print each index separately?

I want to do the error message under each form so that is why I want each of them separate.

I tried with `$v[0]` and nothing appear.

is there a trick or something am I missing?

Comment: If there's something in `$v[0]` then `echo $v[0]` should work. We need more information to diagnose this problem.

Comment: @deceze I'm having bunch of error message that is storing in that array using array_push and now I want to display them in each spot differently.

Comment: What is mean by 'the array index of in PHP'?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk like we have 10 string will be store in the array and I want to print each of them like index of 0, 1, 2 something like that.

Comment: Still not getting. Can you show by sample data? So it will be easy to understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about an associative array, you need to fetch the index directly:

Example:

```
$array = array ('test' => 'value1', 'test2' => 'value2');   
echo $array['test']; // value1
```

You can do a print_r($array) to see the array structure nicely formatted:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($array);?>
</pre>
```

What you're doing instead is fetch a value by its numerical index, like in

```
$array = array('test','test2','test3');
echo $array[0];  // test
```

On a further note, you can check beforehand if a key exists using [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
var_dump(array_key_exists('test2',$array));  // (bool) TRUE
```

Answer (score 9):

[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will print indexes in array.

```
print_r(array_keys($arr));
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly that was needed to print custom index number for non-associative array.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `foreach` loop then you're probably using an associative array (i.e. `$v['inputName']`) So, using `$v[0]` wouldn't work because the indexes aren't defined by numbers - they are defined by lettering. You could use a `foreach` loop to then associate all the values to the numbered indexes and then us it like that.

```
$x = array();
foreach($v as $key=>$value) {

   $x[count($x)] = $key;

}

echo $x[0];
```

In that case `$x[0]` would work

Answer (score 3):

You can use php [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to get all keys. If Its Associative Array,

```
$array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => color
    [1] => size
)
```

Other way is :

```
if(is_array($v){
    foreach($v as $k=>$value) { 
         echo "<br/>". $k ;  // $k is the key 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Try (from the above page):

```
<?php
  $array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
  print_r(array_keys($array));

  $array = array("blue", "red", "green", "blue", "blue");
  print_r(array_keys($array, "blue"));

  $array = array("color" => array("blue", "red", "green"),
               "size"  => array("small", "medium", "large"));
  print_r(array_keys($array));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) function to print the array :

```
print_r($array)
```

Comment: very true, indeed, it is the easiest :)